# Using Dapper, how do I pass in the values for a sql type as param?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm attempting to use dapper and pass into a stored procedure a list of integers which I have defined here using DDL

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[BrandIDSet] AS TABLE ([BrandID] INT NULL);
```

I've created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_getFilteredCatalogItems 
    @BrandIDSet [dbo].[BrandIDSet] READONLY
```

and attempting to pass in in c# code the value for that parameter as

```
public async Task<PaginatedCatalogItemsVM> GetFilteredCatalogItems(int pageSize, int pageNumber, List<int> brandIDSet)
{
     ..
     string storedProcName = "dbo.usp_getFilteredCatalogItems";
     paginatedItemsVM.CatalogItemResults = await connection.QueryAsync<CatalogItemVM>(storedProcName, new { BrandIDSet = brandIDSet }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

However, dapper does not seem to be converting the list as expected. With the above code, it results in the following SQL getting executed

```
exec dbo.usp_getFilteredCatalogItems @BrandIDSet1=1
```

Which isn't right, since BrandIDSet1 is not the name of the parameter. Arg. 
Thus, it results in

> SqlException: @BrandIDSet1 is not a parameter for procedure usp_getFilteredCatalogItems.

How do I get the type to convert to the proper SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass DataTable for proper result. You can try the code below;

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BrandID", typeof(int)));
foreach (var id in brandIDSet)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["BrandId"] = id;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

string storedProcName = "dbo.usp_getFilteredCatalogItems";
paginatedItemsVM.CatalogItemResults = await connection.QueryAsync<CatalogItemVM>(storedProcName, new { BrandIDSet = dt }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: what is BrandId type in sql parameter? Can you show content of usp_getFilteredCatalogItems?

Comment: It is int as written in question. My answer only focuses how to send list of integers to a stored procedure.

Comment: yes that is what I need. But I do not understand how to declare list of int in sql stored procedure

Comment: @toha Actually you can't declare as in C# but you can declare a table with an integer column as work around.